# NOT NULL constraint failed: users_user.email

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I just created a custom user Model and a custom user manager. I'm able to create superuser with manage.py createsuperuser, but when it comes to update, delete or even create a new user on the admin panel, I have this wierd error :

> NOT NULL constraint failed: users_user.email

I have no idea how to fix it and I'm just stuck. Here is my model and my manager :

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    #custom create_user method
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        print(email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        print(user)
        return user

    #Custom create_super_user method
    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email = email,
            password = password
        )
        user.admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    #setting up Choices for interest, Must add other fields ...
    #interests = MultiSelectField(
    #    max_length = 2,
    #    choices = INTERESTS_CHOICES
    #)


    #Setting up a Ranking System

    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=50,
        unique=True,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=25,
        unique=True,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    reputation = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    rank = models.CharField(choices=RANKING_CHOICES, max_length=5, default="basic")
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bio = models.TextField(
        max_length=300,
        default="default Bio",
        blank=True
    )
    objects = UserManager()
    #Setting email to be the main source of authentication
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    #Super User Only
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password']

    #def get_absolute_url(self):
        #use reverse + nom de l'url de view

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def set_user_league(self):
        if 15 <= self.reputation < 40:
            self.rank = "gold"
        elif 40 <= self.reputation < 80:
            self.rank = "platinium"
        else:
            self.rank = "diamond"

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        print(f" is {self.email} admin ? ")
        return self.admin

    def has_perm(self, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, obj=None):
        return True
```

What should I do ? I have been stuck for hours. Thank you !

Comment: What is the value of `email`? You print it, so it probably prints something?

Comment: when creating a user, it seems that create_user isn't even called. I cannot see any of my prints

Comment: well, after running makemigrations and migrate, when updating an existing user email, the new email is set to None :/

Answer (score 0):

make your model as a OneToOne relationship to User model. then rewrite the email field with `null=True`

Comment: I want to create my own user model. I don't want to use a onetoone field

Comment: So rewrite it in your abstract class.
`email = models.EmailField(null=True, max_length=255)`

Comment: but it is my main source of authentication

Comment: did u registered your modified User model in admin panel?

Comment: why did u just don't write your own model from scratch and don't use django User model?